# React export table as pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to export data from table to pdf in order to let user download it.
However, I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752113/export-to-pdf-in-react-table) solution, it didn't worked
My `npm install` faced an error during installation

[image: My npm error here]

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/huanz/tableExport)

```
var tableExport = require('table-export');
tableExport('myTable', 'myName', 'pdf');
```

Following attributes from `tableExport` are *tablename*, *filename*, *the file type*