# I want to generate this table on a PDF. Any suggestions on what library to use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, documentation-generation

This is the table:

[image]

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l8MiztpYH60so-LX1X3NR-9mZo1AAoxxzmCX8meAwJE/edit?usp=sharing) is where the table comes from. I have also checked `react-pdf` but table generation is not yet implemented and it is a [huge pain to create this using plain CSS](https://github.com/Chagall/react-pdf-table-example).

Comment: *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the inbuilt JavaScript table or export the bootstrap data table and modify it. It should be really useful since you can control the view there. If you're looking for a library then maybe this existing question might be helpful. [Export to PDF in React-Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752113/export-to-pdf-in-react-table)